# SARIMA initial identification of parameters

Tags: time-series, arima, stationarity, seasonality, acf-pacf

I am trying to fit a time series with SARIMA models, where the seasonal period is 7. The figure shows the series after applying a logarithmic transformation and differentiating it for the regular (d=1) and seasonal (s=7) part.

I can observe that the ACF and PACF plots suggest a mixed ARMA model for the regular part, but I don't know which configuration of the model should I try first based on the plots. Nor the configuration I should use for the seasonal part.

[image: Stationary series (obtained by differencing for the regular d=1 and the seasonal s=7 parts)]

The raw log series is:
[image]
[image]

and the differenced log series d=1:
[image]

The acf and pacf are:
[image]

So, how should I interpret that acf and pacf?

Comment: ACF and PACF indicate that SMA(1) would be a good starting point because seasonal lags in PACF are falling gradually and you have 1 significant seasonal lag in ACF. But, is seasonal differencing necessary? You also might want to check if the series is an ARCH/GARCH process.

Comment: The first plot suggests you may have overdifferenced your time series. How does the original time series look? Did you have a good reason to difference (the logarithm of) it? What transformation of the data do the ACF and PACF correspond to? Raw, logged, diff-logged?

Comment: Thank you for your response. The series had seasonality of m=7 and I tested seasonal stationarity with  Osborn-Chu-Smith-Birchenhall (OCSB) and Canova-Hansen (CH) tests. The first concludes that seasonal differencing was not necessary but the second but the second claimed that it did. I chose to differentiate (D=1) and indeed I overdifferenced my series.

Comment: Could you update your post with graphs for log-transformed, undifferenced data (raw, ACF, PACF)? Consider answering my remaining questions, too. Also, when responding to my comment, please include @RichardHardy as otherwise I do not get notified. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have already updated the post @RichardHardy. As you can see, I have good reasons to difference the log series, although it was a mistake to differentiate the seasonal part.

Comment: There seems to be calendar effects breaking the weekly pattern and obscuring the question of seasonal differentiation. Also due to the beginning of the series, no differentiation will lead to an approximately stationary series.